# mingw/wish daily prompt to update git?

Tags: git, windows-7, mingw

Every day about 2:30 p.m. EST I receive this popup:

[image: Update Git Prompt]

Of course the *version* changes every now and then.  I have two questions:

1. Is the timing of this configurable?  I tried to find a config file but came up empty (or gave up too soon!)
2. When I click "OK", where does it download and install git?  From what I can see in the git subdirectory, it looks like I've been running git version 2.17.1.windows.2,  which I can find here:

> ```
> C:\Users\brittg2>where git
> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
>
> C:\Users\brittg2>dir "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"
>  Volume in drive C is System
>  Volume Serial Number is 0240-BAB8
>
>  Directory of C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
>
> 2018/05/29  06:08 PM            39,192 git.exe
>                1 File(s)         39,192 bytes
>                0 Dir(s)  22,077,034,496 bytes free
> ```

which was last updated on 5 May 2018, indicating that accepting the download offer doesn't seem to change my running version.

I answered my first question.  It's in Task Scheduler:

[image: Task Scheduler]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7fmG.png
```

Update 26 feb 2019: I ran the command in the scheduled task from the command line and it errored out:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" update-git-for-windows
Git for Windows 2.17.1.windows.2 (64bit)
Update 2.21.0.windows.1 is available
Download and install Git for Windows 2.21.0 [N/y]? y
##O#- #
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: on Windows 8 and 10, the notificiation, [since Git for Windows 2.15.1 (Nov. 2017)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.15.1.windows.1) is [less intrusive (PR 1335)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1335): see [commit 1007b6c](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/commit/1007b6c2252cf79d19a8631b26953901a14ccb74)

> ### `git-update`: show a toast notification on Windows 8/10
>
> This is a much less intrusive way to notify the user of any updates than
>   to pop up a modal dialog.

But for Windows 7, I would go with:

- the latest portable version, like the [`PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.21.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe) (released 40 minutes ago)
- uncompressed anywhere you want: `c:\gits\PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit`
- with a symlink (folder junction): `mklink /J c:\gits\latest c:\gits\PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit`

That way:

- you control when you want to update
- your PATH remains always c:\gits\latest\bin
- each update involve changing latest to the new portable Git installation folder
- an "uninstall" means simply deleting that folder.

Comment: Well that's interesting to be sure.  However what I want to know is when I accept Mingw's offer to update git, where does it put it?  e.g. my git path is `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe` but that hasn't been updated since "dir "\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is D4EA-5262

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

05/29/2018  07:08 PM            39,192 git.exe
               1 File(s)         39,192 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  890,214,043,648 bytes free"

Comment: @user1443098 By default (when using the msi installer, not the portable version): `C:\Program Files\Git\ ` On Windows 7, check if you are using 32 ou 64bit (because then it would be `C:\Program Files(86)\Git\` for 32 bits)

Comment: OK -- so that tells me that the updater doesn't work (and doesn't issue error messages either.)  Still that's good to know!

Comment: @user1443098 type "where git" in a CMD to check what, in your current PATH is found for the installation folder of git.

Comment: I just posted that:  `where git` returns `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`

Comment: So this remains unadwered

Comment: @user1443098 Yes: the portable version remains easier to manage in your case.